# Tableau: How to do YTD and MTD calculations in MSAS cube?

Tags: mdx, tableau-api, olap-cube

There are very less resources and examples pertaining this question.
Please refer to the screenshot below. It shows the dimension and measure names of my cube.

I referred to the link below for YTD and MTD calculations.
community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5293
I have been using the following calculated member to find out MTD

```
Sum
(
  MTD
  (
    StrToMember("[DIM TIME].[Date].&[" + Format(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy") + "]")
  )
 ,[Measures].[SALES AMOUNT]
)
```

It does not give me any result.

Note: This link is helpful too
community.tableau.com/message/206847#206847

Here are some screenshots
[Shows the dimensions and measures I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuPq9.png)
[(The member I created)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1iYf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer but an initial check I would do is the following.

Add your StrToMember to a simplified script without the calculations

```
SELECT
[Measures].[SALES AMOUNT] on 0,
StrToMember("[DIM TIME].[Date].&[" + Format(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy") + "]") ON 1
FROM [YourCubeName];
```

Does this give a result?

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply. I found a work around inside tableau filter itself which allows me to do YTD and MTD calculations.